# ¿Por qué accede al método delete?

Tags: php, html, html5, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo los siguientes métodos:

```
public function update(ClienteFormRequest $request, $id)
{

    Cliente::where('cli_no', '=', $id)

        ->update(['cli_nombre' => $request->get('cli_nombre'),
            'cli_apellido1'=> $request->get('cli_apellido1'),
            'cli_apellido2'=> $request->get('cli_apellido2'),
            'cli_fecha_nacimiento'=> $request->get('cli_fecha_nacimiento'),
            'cli_localidad'=> $request->get('cli_localidad'),
            'cli_paypal'=> $request->get('cli_paypal')]);

    User::where('id_usuario', '=', auth()->user()->id_usuario)

        ->update(['name'=>$request->get('name'),
            'email'=>$request->get('email'),
            'password'=>bcrypt($request->get('password'))]);


    return Redirect::to('cliente/mismo');
}

public function destroy(ClienteFormRequest $request,$id)
{
    $cliente=Cliente::where('cli_no',$id)->get();

    $editado=(User::where('u_cliente_id', $cliente[0]->id_cliente)
        ->where('password', bcrypt($request->get('password')))
        ->update(['u_activo'=>0]))?true:false;;

        if($editado){

            Cliente::where('cli_no',$id)->update(['cli_activo' => 0]);

            return route('logout');
        }else{
            return Redirect::to('cliente/mismo')->with('message', 'Borrado fallido');
        }
}
```

Y el siguiente código en la vista .blade.php:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Editar Usuario cliente: <strong>{{$cliente[0]->nombre}}</strong></h4></div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('mismo.update', $cliente[0]->cli_no, $cliente[0] ) }}">
                        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        @if (Session::has('message'))
                            <div class="alert alert-warning">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
                        @endif


                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" >
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Actualizar datos
                                </button>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#modal-delete-{{$cliente[0]->cli_no}}" data-toggle="modal">Borrar tu cuenta</button>
                                @include('cliente.mismo.modal')
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como veis he incluido un modal que es el siguiente:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-delete-{{$cliente[0]->cli_no}}">
<form action="{{ route('mismo.destroy', $cliente[0]->cli_no, $cliente[0]) }}" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden>x</span> </button> <h4 class="modal-title">
                    Eliminar Cliente</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p> Confirme si desea Eliminar su cuenta <strong>{{$cliente[0]->nombre}}</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"> Cerrar </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Vale, el problema es que cuando le doy al botón de submit de la página principal(la primera) se activa el método destroy(especificado en el modal o vista segundas, que incluyo en la primera) en vez de el update que es la acción que tengo especificada para el formulario o vista primera, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Solo deberías poner el código relevante. No olvides dar un tour por el sitio y leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Vale ahora lo edito, gracias por el comentario

Comment: No es que sea mal pensado pero el título "¿Por qué *me entra* en el delete?" suena super raro, debería usar algo como "¿Por qué accede al método delete cuando no es lo esperado?" no digo que ponga eso, sólo sugiero que cuidemos de poner cosas raras en los títulos.

Comment: Vale perdona Jorge, es que no tengo mucha experiencia en foros...

Comment: Yo la verdad veo que el título está bien, de lo contrario yo mismo lo habría modificado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón del problema es que **tienes un formulario dentro de otro**, cosa que semánticamente es incorrecta. Si vemos, un formulario es independiente de otro; cada uno tiene su propio `action` y `method`.

Te recomendaría que hicieras el `include` del modal fuera del formulario. No es necesario anidarlo en el formulario para que las propiedades Bootstrap funcionen.

Comment: ¿Cómo haría entonces para que se validara en el formulario del delete la password?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el concepto ¿te refieres a que confirme con la contraseña el borrado del registro? Te recomendaría usar otro `input` dentro del modal y procesar esa información en el método destroy. Recordemos que cada formulario es independiente uno del otro, no es buena práctica tomar información de un formulario a expensas de otro, mejor fuerza al usuario a llenar de nuevo la contraseña.

Comment: Exáctamente lo que me has dicho, eso es lo que quería, lo que no se es como recoger la password después, ¿tengo que hacer un controlador para el borrado?¿Cómo cogería el valor en el formulario? ¿Así quizá?"{{ route('mismo.destroy', $cliente[0]->cli_no, $password) }}"

Comment: ¿Obtener la contraseña del input sin hacer submit?

Comment: No eso no, ya lo he averiguado de todos modos, ahora lo que me pasa es que el bcrypt aunque le meto los mismos valores no me reconoce que es la misma password

Comment: Te recomendaría abrir otra pregunta para poder apoyarte en ese detalle.

Answer (score 2):

Es incorrecto anidar formularios, tanto por especificación ([Ver detalle](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#association-of-controls-and-forms)) como por la forma como funcionan los navegadores (normalmente funcionan muy similar a como lo indica la especificación).

Teniendo en cuenta que es un simple modal, lo más fácil es que el include de su plantilla lo hagas fuera del `<form>` de actualización:

```
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Actualizar datos
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#modal-delete-{{$cliente[0]->cli_no}}" data-toggle="modal">Borrar tu cuenta</button>
                    @include('cliente.mismo.modal')
```

O dependiendo como esté tu estilo, puedes hacer algo un poco menos ortodoxo:

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Actualizar datos
                            </button>
                </form>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#modal-delete-{{$cliente[0]->cli_no}}" data-toggle="modal">Borrar tu cuenta</button>
                            @include('cliente.mismo.modal')
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: ¿El formulario tiene que cerrarse antes? Entonces el botón me va a salir por donde le de la gana

Comment: Sí, básicamente el formulario debe estar "cerrado" antes de iniciar el otro, también podrías dejar el botón dentro el formulario, y activarlo con javascript.

Comment: No creo que sea necesario usar Javascript (jQuery) para evitar evitar el submit, ya que los botones tipo `button` no realizan el submit. Además Bootstrap ya se encarga de mostrar el formulario con la propiedad `data-target`.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, pues nunca uso Bootstrap (ni jQuery), es la costumbre de trabajar con otros escenarios un poco más complejos.